# How to unwrap data from nested props?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

Why my variables after unwrapping from props stops being reactive?

I three components - parent, second for displaying and third for updating data depending on input (code is very simplified here).

Third component is updating parent via event and that updated value should be passed to child. I know that architecture might smell. I'm not using any store.

What I would expect is that emit is updating value and on `Child1` new value is displayed. That happen if I do not unwrap unwrapped prop.

```
// Parent.vue
<template>
  <ChildA :data="data"/>
  <ChildB @update-data="updateData"/>
</template>
<script setup>
import { reactive, toRefs } from "vue";
const { data } = toRefs(
  reactive({ data: { latestEvent: { status: "fail" } } })
);

const updateData = (event) => {
  data.value = event;
};
</script>
```

```
// ChildA.vue
<template>
  {{ latestStatus }}
</template>
<script setup>
import { computed, toRefs } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  data: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => {},
  },
});
const { data } = toRefs(props);
const { latestEvent } = data.value;
const latestStatus = computed(() => data.value.latestEvent.status);
// const latestStatus = computed(() => latestEvent.status); THAT'S NOT REACTIVE
</script>
```

```
// ChildB.vue
<template>
  <select v-model="status" @change="onChange()">
    <option value="in progress">in progress</option>
    <option value="new">new</option>
    <option value="fail">fail</option>
  </select>
</template>
<script setup>
import { reactive, ref, toRefs } from "vue";
const status = ref("");
const emit = defineEmits(["updateData"]);

const onChange = () => {
  emit(
    "updateData",
    toRefs(
      reactive({
        latestEvent: { status: status },
      })
    )
  );
};
</script>
```

How to make my variables reactive after unwrapping from prop?

I would imagine something like this:

```
const { data } = toRefs(props);
const { latestEvent } = toRefs(data);
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown where these values come from and why it doesn't work. It's "lastEvent" in one place and "latestEvent" in another

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask. I have updated comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the  whole `data` and not just `data.latestEvent.status` value is changed, destructuring it early like `const { latestEvent } = data.value` disables the reactivity. `latestEvent` refers `data.latestEvent` object that exists at the time when setup function runs.

What happens here is basically:

```
let foo = { bar: { baz: 1 } };
let bar = foo.bar;
let baz = foo.bar.baz;
foo.bar = { baz: 2 };
console.log(bar !== foo.bar); // true
console.log(baz === 1); // true
```

It should always be:

```
const latestStatus = computed(() => data.value.latestEvent.status);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Even if i do not like that, that's clear for me know. Many thanks!